# HTML li displayed as table-cell cannot be floated right

Tags: html, css

I trying to make bar using `ul` element with `li` childs, displayed as `table-cell`.

Some `li` should to be at left side, another ones - in right side.

But here's problem: "right ones" go out of `ul` staight line.

HTML:

```
<ul style="height:50px;background:green;">
    <li>li-1</li>
    <li>li-2</li>
    <li style="float: right">li-3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yamaha/n4jrhx46/ You will see, that `li-3` went out of my bar. I want to let it back (using table-cell for vertical align. line-height not suitable here in my case), but don't know how.

How to fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4jrhx46/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4jrhx46/3/

Comment: list-style is what you want.

Comment: what I can tell you is `vertical-algin: middle`, does not work with `display: table-cell`. so you need to use `display:table` and `vertical-algin: middle` on `ul`.

Comment: Are you trying for this????? http://jsfiddle.net/n4jrhx46/4/

Comment: @Lal, i losing vertical align middle in this case, which i have mentioned in Q. So it isn't option.

Comment: @KheemaPandey, i tried what you suggested, but vertical align doesnt work now: http://jsfiddle.net/Yamaha/om9yk8y1/

Comment: @Yamaha you have to use `line-height` as well. see link. http://jsfiddle.net/om9yk8y1/1/

Comment: @KheemaPandey, thank you for suggestion, but i wrote "line-height not suitable here in my case" in Q, because it doesn't work for images etc.

Comment: @Yamaha so in your layout 2 images will be on left and one image will be on right? what if you add an extra image? Is your layout  still fine?

Comment: @KheemaPandey, actually, left side's li should to be the text, right side - is image. It's my fail, that i didn't specify it. So i updated jsfiddle to let you see what i actually want: http://jsfiddle.net/Yamaha/om9yk8y1/7/ But you see, that image isn't middle aligned, thats why i can't use line-height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any floated element that has a specified display value of `table-cell` has a computed value for display of `block`. See [the CSS 2.1 spec, Section 9.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

So you're on a loser there. Instead, drop the `float:right` and make use of the table layout model and text alignment to move the content into position. Something like

```
li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/n4jrhx46/5/

Answer (score 0):

@Yamaha I would suggest you instead of using `display:table-cell` use `display:inline` .

As per your suggested code you only need to add a `line-height` to make vertically align. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/om9yk8y1/6/)**.

```
ul {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;/* This property have been added*/
}
li.right{ float:right; padding-right:12px;}
```